# Using VBA to compare 2 lists

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Every month, I export 2 lists from an SAP database that get saved as seperate Excel files. List A contains all defects found in the last month. List B contains all of the defects caused by an outside vendor. I do a lot of formatting to ListA before it is a complete report, and I have a macro that does most of it perfectly. I just can't seem to get the list comparison piece working.

My manual process is to insert a new column D in List A, type `=VLOOKUP(A2,ListB!$A$2:$N$946,1,FALSE)` into cell D2, and copy it down to the end (the range of the look-up table varies depending on the size of ListB). I would then filter the list to exclude "#N/A"s and change the value of the "Cause" column (now column E) to "Vendor" for the remaining rows. FInally, I delete the VLOOKUP column.

I thought automating this process would be easy, but it has given me several migranes. I could get the job done with nested For Loops [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666673/vba-excel-compare-two-lists-for-matches-output-results-on-separate-sheet), but I feel that there has to be a more efficient way.

First, I tried the Vlookup Aplication Function within a For Loop:

```
'ListA and ListB declared as Worksheets and set
Dim aRange as Range, bRange as Range
Dim last row As Integer
Set aRange = ListA.Range("A1")
Set aRange = Range(aRange, aRange.End(xlToRight))
Set aRange = Range(aRange, aRange.End(xlDown))
Set bRange = ListB.Range("A1")
Set bRange = Range(bRange, bRange.End(xlToRight))
Set bRange = Range(bRange, bRange.End(xlDown))

'I'm skipping over the stuff that would be here but don't need help with

lastrow = ListA.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    ListA.Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListA.Cells(i, 1), bRange, 3, False)
    If ListA.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "#N/A" Then ListA.Cells(i, 5).Value = "Vendor"
Next i
```

Unfortunately, this method encountered a Runtime error at the first cell that would have returned a #N/A error.

For my second attempt, I recorded a macro while going through my manual process and then tried changing the returned code from this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Sheet1!R2C1:R946C14,1,FALSE)"
Range("D2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D1033"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("D2:D1033").Select
```

to this:

```
Set aRange = ListA.Range("D2")
Set aRange = Range(aRange, aRange.End(xlDown))
Set bRange = ListB.Range("A1")
Set bRange = Range(bRange, bRange.End(xlToRight))
Set bRange = Range(bRange, bRange.End(xlDown))
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3]," & bRange & ",1,FALSE)"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=aRange, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

This method isn't working, according to the Runtime Error, due to a type missmatch. I can only assume that it doesn't like me sticking a range varaible in the middle of the formula, but I don't know of another way of making sure that the look-up table is the right size.

Any help (which approach is more efficient, how to get one of these working, or even a different approach I hadn't thought of) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the runtime error is actually correct from the `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` function - that's the equivalent of **#N/A!** that the excel formula would return. By checking for the error, we can find the N/A values (or, as we do in this case, by checking for success, we can write out the `Vendor` string)

```
On Error Resume Next 'don't error out on failure to find

For i = 2 To lastrow
   Err.Clear 
   'clear out errors, as we don't want to see whatever the previous error was
   ListA.Cells(i, 4).Value = _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListA.Cells(i, 1), bRange, 3, False)
   ' if no error, then we have a vendor
   If Err.Number=0 Then ListA.Cells(i, 5).Value = "Vendor"
Next i

'reset error trapping back to default 
'(or to whatever your normal error handling is
On Error Goto 0
```